# How to overcome asynchronous non-blocking NOT returning values in times?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, nonblocking

I am creating an array of JSON objects which is then stored in mongodb.
Each JSON object contains a number of fields - each being populated before I save the object to mongodb.

Some of the Objects attributes are populated by making API calls to other websites such as last.fm but the returned value is not quick enough to populate the attribute before the object is saved to mongodb.

How can I wait for all attributes of an object to be populated before saving it?  I did try async.waterfall but it still falls through without waiting and I end up with a database filled with documents with empty fields..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: `async.waterfall` (or one of the other `async` methods) should work. Can you post the code you tried so that we can try to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for controlling asynchrony in JavaScript:

1. Callback pattern: (http://npmjs.org/async) `async.all([...], function (err) {`
2. Promises: (http://npmjs.org/q) `Q.all([...]).then(function () {`
3. Streams: (http://npmjs.org/concat-stream) see also https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

Comment: Hi - Sorry but streams are no good for adding values to a json object, and I've been through all of the async module and it still doesn't 'stop' for content to be populated.  I think Q may be of interest so will try that and will add the code here tomorrow.  Thanks :)

Comment: What's particularly cool about the async module is that each thing in the array is a function.  Inside the function, you call the callback when you're done.  `async.all([..the.array.of.fns..], function (err) {` will call that end function when every function inside the array has called the callback or any of them call it with an error.  It is exactly designed to "stop and wait for content".

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are making multiple API calls to other websites, you may want to try:

```
async.each(api_requests,
    function(api_request, cb) {
        request(api_request, function (error, response, body) {
            /* code */
            /* add to model for Mongo */
            cb();
        });
    },
    function(err) {
        // continue execution after all cbs are received
        /* code */
        /* save to Mongo, etc.. */
    }
);
```

The above example is most applicable when you are making numerous requests following the same format.  Please review the documentation for Waterfall (https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) if the input into your next step depends on the output of the previous step or Parallel (https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) if you have a bunch of unrelated tasks that don't rely on each other.  The great thing about async is that you can nest and string all the functions together to support what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've an array of json objects - each object has a number of attributes.  One of those attributes gets a value from an API call to a 3rd-party (last.fm) not all attributes... so async.each is no good.  I'm trying waterfall - but if you're looping through an array for each waterfall function then it seems it doesn't like the looping.... everything suggests I have to write even more code to keep things asynchronous.  Do I now need an async.DoWhilst in each function of an async.waterfall?

Comment: So you have an array of objects where one of the attributes of those objects gets its value from an API call?  That's exactly what you would want to use `async.each` for.  Simply loop through the array of objects, fill in the non-API-related data fields and then make your API call.  Only use the callback once you actually have the data back from the API as in the above example.  If the function you use to call your API returns before its resolved, it won't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either want to use promises or some sort of callback mechanism. Here's an example of the promise method with [jPromise](https://github.com/jive/jPromise):

```
var jPromise = require('jPromise');
var promises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push(someAsyncApiCall(i));
}

jPromise.when(promises).then(function() {
    saveThingsToTheDb();
});
```

Similarly, without the promise library:

```
var finished = 0;
var toDo = 10;

function allDone() {
    saveThingsToTheDb();
}

for(var i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++) {
    someAsyncApiCall(function() {
        finished++;

        if(finished === toDo) {
            allDone();
        }
    });
}
```

Personally, I prefer the promise method, but that will only that well if the API you're calling returns some sort of a promise. If it doesn't, you'll be SOL and wrap the callback API with promises somehow ([Q does this pretty well](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node)).

Comment: Well since its Node & async it is non-blocking callbacks - just that the code is executed without waiting for previous calls to come back.  For APIs for last.fm they return a json object - so not really a promise, but I will see if it works with Q.  Just funny that there are quite  few things which asynchronous can't handle well.

Comment: What do you mean that the last.fm calls return a JSON object? If you're getting a JSON object via an HTTP call it's either passing it to a callback somewhere or it's blocking. There's no other way to do this (not entirely true, but generally true). If it's passing it to a callback function, you can look at my second example. It more or less show exactly how to do this (or as close as I can get without a code sample from you).

Comment: Sorry I may not have given all info.  But yes the call to last.fm does return a json object as I am making a request, but I am only using a couple of the values within that object (i.e. artist.imglink = lastfm.artistimg).  BUT I also have 8 other attributes of my json object being populated by functions within my code.  So in terms of all the values being returned in a timely manner the imglink from last.fm is returned after everything else, but due to the non-blocking side is left out when the json object is saved.

Comment: Again, if you see my example it shows you how you can wait until async functions finish executing. I'm really not understanding what else you're trying to get done here. Wait until all the async function calls have finished before calling the save to the database. I'll need a code sample if you want any more help.

Comment: Fair point.  I am just trying to see how asynchronous code can fill all values without having to resort to "wait until counter equals total" - as I feel that goes against the point of asynchronous.  I will explore the Promises as it seems to be a 'halfway house'.  Really appreciate your thoughts though, so thank you

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to have a counter, use the promises. It abstracts the counter for you waiting until all of the promises are done before resolving the final promise returned by the `Q.all` or `jPromise.when` functions. It still has the counter, it's juts that the counter is internal to the promise library.